# Long native query getting frozen

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I am using hibernate in my automation testing project, to execute a database 'clean-up routine' that is:

- disabling constraints for all tables in the database
- removing records by ID's that I stored when creating records used for my automation testing
- enabling constraints for all tables in the database

Here is my pseudo code:

```
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private void initialize()
{
    try
    {
        Configuration config = createHibernateConfiguration();
        addAnnotatedClassesForClientDB(config);

        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
        serviceRegistryBuilder.applySettings(config.getProperties());
        serviceRegistry = serviceRegistryBuilder.build();
        sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    }
    catch (HibernateException e)
    {
        logger.error("Problem creating session factory!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Session openSession()
{
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    return session;
}

public void cleanClientDatabase()
{
    Session session = openSession();

    try
    {
        logger.info("Client DB cleaning started...");
        String combinedQuery = // her comes my SQL query

        Query query = session.createNativeQuery(combinedQuery);
        query.executeUpdate();

        closeSession(session);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.error("Failed cleaning Client DB! " + e.getClass().getSimpleName());
        e.printStackTrace();

        session.getTransaction().rollback();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Now from time to time, it sticks at `query.executeUpdate();` in `cleanClientDatabase()` method and will hang there forever, until I manually kill transaction in Microsoft SQL Management studio by PID.

For some reason an exception is never thrown so I can't tell what is the error, I suspect some sort of lock, what can I do to avoid this issue and fix my code?

Thank you.

Comment: Run a database trace to see what query nHibernate  generates.  You can run the code directly in SSMS after you get it from the trace.  It will be comparable.  Sorry to be direct, but don't use nHibernate.  We have a legacy system that uses nHibernate.  On those occasions when no one can stand the pain anymore, we convert sections of nHibernate to stored procedures.  So far, I have not had any stored procedures that ran less than 100x faster than the replaced nHibernate code.  Not optimized stored procedures.  Simple replacements.

Comment: Clearly the query plan is terrible and therefore taking a long time. Without knowing the underlying query (you can get this with a trace maybe), and also the table and index definitions, we can't help